# How to send keys started hidden CMD process

Tags: c#

How to send character key to hidden CMD window?
My code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public void SendText(IntPtr hwnd, string keys)
{
    if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (SetForegroundWindow(hwnd))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(keys);
        }
    }
}

Process p;
int pid;
```

Start Hidden process:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();
    pid = p.Id;
}
```

Send key:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proc1 = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    SetForegroundWindow(proc1.Handle);
    SendKeys.Send("q");
}
```

How to send key the my process? (But my code starting ffmpeg.exe and send "q" key the stop encode)
Thanks the answer.

Comment: What do you want exactly : to send a key press ? Or to stop the process ? Because, if it's the latter, you might want to use your process object to call ffmpeg directly and stop it using the same object

Comment: I want send key "q" and stop ffmpeg. Not kill process.

Comment: @Gabee how do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, with a  ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized or  ProcessWindowStyle.Normal, it works fine. It seems though as there is no way of doing it with  ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send keys to a non-active window, hidden window can't be activated.

Workaround: instead make the window style hidden. You can make it minimized but still you need to activate it to send keys, so you can loop through all the running processes to find your minimized window, activate it then send keys and minimize it again (foreground).

Place this piece of code into your main:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);

[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
public Process telnet = new Process();
```

Here is a prepared method for your (p) process:

```
public void sendkeys(string data)
{
    send = true;
    Process s = Process.GetProcessById(p.Id);
    while (s.ProcessName == p.ProcessName && send)
    {
        while (send)
        {
            IntPtr h = s.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(h);
            SendKeys.SendWait(data);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            send = false;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, to send q >>> `sendKeys("q")`;

Answer (score 0):

During creation of hidden process you have to set `RedirectStandardInput = true`, otherwise your process will not accept incoming keys.

So if you created your process like this:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

You can send message to this process via `StandardInput`

```
if (!process.HasExited)
{
    using (var streamWriter = process.StandardInput)
    {
        // write your message here
        var message = "q";
        streamWriter.WriteLine(message);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();
}
```

For more details go to https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=netframework-4.8